# Body field data disappeared

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

EDIT: Looks like I accidentally changed number of values for this field to 1 - it should be Unlimited. It's working now, thanks everyone.

I don't know what I did but I noticed that all (except the first one) body field data in all the nodes disappeared - they're not even available in editor.

All the data is still in DB (in field_data_body table) but it's not showing on website.

I have no idea how to fix this, has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: I have exact same issue. body data shows in db in field_data_body table but does not show in View or Edit mode. Body is set to '1' but i believe that is correct, and is the same as on the site we duplicated. Also other body fields are set to '1' and they show data fine. Seems to be just one content type affected. the formats on original and live are both filtered_html and again this is working for all other content types - maybe i will fire this in as separate question.

Comment: In my case it was language issue, in that the body field had been changed from translatable = 1 (in field_config) to translatable = 0 (as a result of a feature coming in with different field settings)

Comment: @user33660 add your "EDIT" as an answer and mark the issue as resolved if possible. This would benefit other users having a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

See permission for this field.

In the admin section: /admin/people/permissions

Comment: I'm logged in as administrator and I have all permissions so I don't think that's the problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Also need to check the input format permissions here -

For Full HTML 
admin/config/content/formats/full_html

For Filtered HTML
admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html

For Plain Text
admin/config/content/formats/plain_text